# how to know who called the controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a file which has different type of code for different purposes. and I want them to be called when the controllerAs is having a specific value. I tried many previous answers but most of them are for the controller but I want to know the value of controllerAs. so how can I know the value of controllerAs and how can I use it in an if condition??

```
var challenge_page = {
        name: "web.challenge-main.challenge-page",
        parent: "web.challenge-main",
        url: "/challenge-page/:challengeId",
        templateUrl: baseUrl + "/web/challenge/challenge-page.html",
        controller: 'ChallengeCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'challenge',
        redirectTo: "web.challenge-main.challenge-page.overview",

    var participate = {
        name: "web.challenge-main.challenge-page.participate",
        parent: "web.challenge-main.challenge-page",
        url: "/participate",
        templateUrl: baseUrl + "/web/challenge/participate.html",
        controller: 'ChallengeCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'participate',
        title: 'Participate',
    };
```

In the above code block, I have the directive file two pages. which calls the same controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$state.current` will give you current state information. You can use `$state.current.name` or `$state.current.title` or `any unique attribute specific to the state...` to identify the current page inside controller.

```js
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  
    const challenge_page = {
      name: "challenge-page",
      url: "/challenge-page/:challengeId",
      templateUrl: "/web/challenge/challenge-page.html",
      controller: 'ChallengeCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'challenge',
      title: 'Challenge'
    };

    const participate = {
      name: "participate",
      parent: "challenge-page",
      url: "/participate",
      templateUrl: "/web/challenge/participate.html",
      controller: 'ChallengeCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'participate',
      title: 'Participate'
    };

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/challenge-page/1');

    $stateProvider
    .state(challenge_page)
    .state(participate);
  })
  .run(function($templateCache) {
   $templateCache.put("/web/challenge/challenge-page.html", `
     <h1>ChallengePage</h1> 
     <ul>
       <li><strong>State Name: </strong>{{challenge.currentState.name}}</li>
        <li><strong>Title: </strong>{{challenge.currentState.title}}</li>
      </ul>
      <hr />
     <blockquote>
       <ui-view></ui-view>
      </blockquote>
    `);
   $templateCache.put("/web/challenge/participate.html", `
     <h1>Participate</h1> 
     <ul>
       <li><strong>State Name: </strong>{{participate.currentState.name}}</li>
        <li><strong>Title: </strong>{{participate.currentState.title}}</li>
      </ul>
    `);
    })
  .controller('ChallengeCtrl', function($state) {
   this.currentState = $state.current;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.24/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <a ui-sref="challenge-page({challengeId: 1})" ui-sref-active="active">Challenge</a>
  <a ui-sref="participate" ui-sref-active="active">Participage</a>

  <ui-view></ui-view>
</div>
```